# Location of GPS-data file?

Tags: android, gps, filesystems, tracking

I am interestes in "seeing" the GPS or location history raw-data of my rooted android device. I had a look in the the `/data/gps/log/` folder and it has interestingly named files but they seem empty...

> Which file or files contain this "raw gps data"? Do these files even exist?

I came across another [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40558/gps-location-log) which talks about `cache.wifi` and `cache.cell` files which I am not able to find neither using RootBrowser nor the command `find / -name "cache.cell"` in TerminalEmulator.

Thanxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turn out the raw GPS-data is not on the phone itself but in the modem!
(... or may be even worse: it is in the Network)

Modems are usually full GNU/Linux-systems with proprietary and closed firmware violating the GPL and influenced by the 3GPP-Consortium.

it is possible to extract GPS information if you manage to get into that tiny computer. Sometimes serial-console helps, it all depends on how the modem is connected to the main CPU and how you interact with your main system.

I used this as a reference with a particular WWAN-modem:
https://wiki.mobian-project.org/doku.php?id=location
it is the one used on a great project: **the PinePhone**

and managed to get the GPS-data. Here is an example of raw data from the link above:

```
$ sudo mmcli -m 0 --location-get
... Sometimes there is additional 3GPP (cell phone) location data here ...
  --------------------------
  GPS  |               nmea: $GPGSA,A,3,13,15,20,21,,,,,,,,,2.8,2.6,1.0,1*19
       |                     $GPRMC,215904.00,A,2518.123453,N,072.1111,W,0.0,21.7,310720,10.8,W,A,V*41
       |                     $GPGSV,3,1,12,05,20,084,22,10,06,272,21,13,51,059,32,15,81,123,34,1*6C
$GPGSV,3,2,12,18,67,295,28,20,35,284,29,21,08,313,29,23,,,30,1*58
$GPGSV,3,3,12,29,21,205,21,30,09,036,26,02,,,,07,,,,1*65
       |                     $GPVTG,21.7,T,32.5,M,0.0,N,0.0,K,A*23
       |                     $GPGGA,215904.00,2518.123453,N,07211.11111,W,1,04,21.1,114.4,M,-36.0,M,,*64
       |                utc: 215904.00
       |          longitude: -72.11111
       |           latitude: 25.123453
       |           altitude: 114.400000
```

there are more resources on the internet, if I find a better one, I'll expand this answer

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/1.0.0/mmcli.8.html
https://electronproton.com/mmcli-command-examples/